# how to transform strin array in to array of objects with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, data-structures

I have this array:

```
data: [
  ‘big text 1 here.’,
  ‘big text 2 here followed by list:’,
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  ‘big text 3 here followed by list:’,
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  ‘big text 4 here.’
],
```

I want to turn it to something like:

```
data: [
  { 
   text: ‘big text 1 here.’
   list: []
  },
  { 
   text: ‘big text 2 here followed by list:’
   list: [
     '-this is list item;',
     '-this is another list item;'
   ]
  },
  { 
   text: ‘big text 3 here followed by list:’
   list: [
     '-this is list item;',
     '-this is another list item;',
     '-this is another list item;',
   ]
  },
  { 
   text: ‘big text 4 here.’
   list: []
  },
],
```

I am trying to achieve this this way

```
interface item {
  text: string;
  list: string[];
};

const newArr: item[] = [];

this.item.content.forEach((x, i) => {
  if(x.startsWith('-') && x.endsWith(';')) {
    //this is bullet list, need to add that to the previous item...
  } else {
    newArr.push({ text: x, list: []});
  }
});
```

I am not sure if I am doing it in a right way, because there is no way I can think of how to access previous element in newArr; Any ideas how to do it proper way?

That is the output that I want to have based on that data:

```
<p>big text 1 here</p>
<p>big text 2 here followed by list:</p>
<ul>
  <li>this is list item</li>
  <li>this is another list item</li>
</ul>
<p>big text 3 here followed by list</p>
<ul>
  <li>this is list item</li>
  <li>this is another list item</li>
  <li>this is another list item</li>
<p>big text 4 here</p>
```

Comment: Any particular reason for the smart-quote characters? `‘` and `’`?

Comment: oh, seems copy-pasting issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this

```js
interface DataItem {
    text: string
    list: string[]
}

function isListItem(item: string): boolean {
    return item.startsWith('-') && item.endsWith(';')
}

const transformedData = data.reduce<DataItem[]>((acc, item) => {
    // if item is list item
    if (isListItem(item)) {
        // get last DataItem from acc
        const lastDataItem = acc[acc.length - 1]

        // and use it as list item's parent
        if (lastDataItem) {
            lastDataItem.list.push(item)
        } else {
            console.error(`Parent text not found for list item ${item}`)
        }

        return acc
    }

    // if item is not list item, use it as new parent/DataItem
    const dataItem: DataItem = {
        text: item,
        list: []
    }

    return [...acc, dataItem]
}, [])
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGByAIwEsBzGKAUwA9YBGGACwoCcKA6PAGh32LMpowATIxYUYAMxAAbaSADuFODAIBPGNKLQAXFx54AtFAZaYpzdDOUAtgG49uQ8dOmEYEMZYatsIjfvcjnzk1LAAzKKskjJyispq3joO+EYmEGbpFr7+yU5pGTBuHkzMidkUdrmpLulFnqVZVhUB+sECsAAskex4WAC6WFhEYJTMEgjA4gAiSAgAkjYwAN48uO3aMNDMwySrZRtbOxgDAL6DEgCuYMBQROAZADI+CxUAFH4VB1DbYCQAlBsCCAZBQ3Ms9qwoBdmGAmtY2NAEMwoBAAOp+BivQx4P4wABkeLhbAoYDgaIxWPsfywZywoEgsG+bggUmY1iUM2QaHgszYrDgF0mAB5OfMbMcAHyvV4TYCcOG41AS8G4XAAejVZgkcIKjQ+1j2RG17wgT2gL2s7xsf1xK1V9pgGpgJAosGkCEsootkmYIGshWAwD29vplnd0C9i3QsowsrY0hJJGMMAMMFoA2DqqdbmUFwg4j8hUyPjheHSAAckSSoJncEaYK9w1BIxVbbWHU2W-Csmxy3nMfrqQ7VScYBRpPmVcOHaGQcTmL7mK8AAYABSrIxCgncsCkV2UrLKOoAJEt9Sdl0Pp7TpzBIdDYbK9jes5r6-qCjuj-r5XmC7APRgMAKHkGBK1YEY1S7PZQ1gRBkAtDYu25O1p3WOFAmnLINmOZ9Bnte8YUwNgSNleV4LFCpTnlY5qTpcAIDnOQSFeJZyGYZlWXZOBRRgE4-iAA)

Comment: any ideas on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72013461/how-to-alter-reduce-function-so-it-produce-different-result ?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for ngTemplateOutlet option for generating li based on your list array.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data">
   <ng-container
       *ngTemplateOutlet="
          !(item.startsWith('-') && item.endsWith(';')) ? ulTemplate : bulletItem;
         context: { $implicit: item }
     "
     >
   </ng-container>
</ul>

<ng-template #ulTemplate let-item>
   <li>{{ item }}</li>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #bulletItem let-item>
  <ul>
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
  </ul >
</ng-template>
```

Now, this way you have redere the right ng-template based on your start character.
Complete demo in this link [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cejqvx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It is interesting idea but this method creates unwanted html structure. And secondly only bulletItems should be wrapped into <ul> as <li> items. To solve the second issue the `"ul *ngFor="let item of data"` can be changed to div `*ngFor="let item of data"`, and  `#ulTemplate <li>` can be changed to `<p>` tag. But then each `<li>` element will be wrapped in to `<div><ul>` if you see what I mean https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-221qf4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @sreginogemoh then what type of structure did you wanted ? Can you show any image for reference ?

Comment: just updated the questions with such details

Comment: @sreginogemoh then I slightly updated code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ztxgjc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html Please check this out and let me know further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following below snippet

```js
let data = [
  'big text 1 here.',
  'big text 2 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  'big text 3 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  'big text 4 here.'
];

function format_array_to_object(data) {
    let new_data = [];
  let previous_data = {};
  data.forEach( function( item, key ){
    if ( item.trim().charAt(0) === '-' ) {
       previous_data.list.push( item );
    } else {
      if ( Object.keys(previous_data).length !== 0 ) {
        new_data.push(previous_data);
        previous_data = {};
        let current_elem = { text: item, list:[] };
        previous_data = current_elem;
      } else {
        let current_elem = { text: item, list:[] };
        previous_data = current_elem;
      }

      if ( ( key + 1 ) === data.length ) {
        new_data.push(previous_data);
      }

    }
  } );
  return new_data;
}

console.log(format_array_to_object(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just saying your strings don't have the correct quotations marks, `’` and `'` are not the same and `’` won't work for a string.