# how to alter reduce function so it produce different result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, reduce

I have this array:

```
data: [
  '+section1+',
  'big text 1 here.',
  'big text 2 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '+section2+',
  'big text 3 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '+section3+', 
  'big text 4 here.'
],
```

I want to transform that array into

```
"data": [
   {
    section: "section1",
    content: [
    {
      "text": "big text 1 here.",
      "list": []
    },
    }
    {
      "text": "big text 2 here followed by list:",
      "list": [
        "-this is list item;",
        "-this is another list item;"
      ]
    },
    ]
   }
   {
    section: "section2"
    content:[
    {
      "text": "big text 3 here followed by list:",
      "list": [
        "-this is list item;",
        "-this is another list item;",
        "-this is another list item;"
      ]
    },
    ]
   }
   {
   section: "section3",
   content: [
    {
      "text": "big text 4 here.",
      "list": []
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
```

I have this code that doing about [that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGByAaggFNgoBLcARjwBpcd8AjcgcximIA9YqYALYgCdiAOjqM8Ldpx4wATAOHEYAMxAAbDSADuxODCYBPGBvLQAXBNx4AtFH7mYTs9GecAtgG5r%20e44hnQIQwEAdhU3NYck8fWkkiUgpweToGG2kOblgAZiURNU1tPQNjSMtfOwcnFyj3Ym9K-xrg0PChcujYpurApxCwwQ7XLoa4yUzZWAAWfLE8LABdLCxyME4hVQRgFQARJAQASU8YAG9GXCmLGGghNdYLzuvb%204xlgF8V1QBXMDJKMBBAAyUWODQAFDEGs8oHcwKwAJTXJggTTEEJnR4iKDfISAqEeUTQBBCKAQADqMX44LseARMAAZAz6oTiGA4BSqTSfAisJ8sKBILBYSEIOohB59PtkGh4AdRCI4N8dgAeaVHTxvAB84PB22A9AJ9NQWsxuFwAHoLc5VCygp0WY9yLbIRAQdAwR5IZ4EfTzuaAzArTBWMRYBoEG51Z61EIQB4YPrHgHBW4I9Boyd0PqMPrRBo2awHDBbDAqMtk%20bgyEDN8SO5E4ERiy8IEAA4ktlQSu4Z0wcHpqCZhp%20nuBwfDwkjURtuvUo1j94wYgaev%20wMb1No0TCONCcEAAwACp31lk5G1Cr8DOKHQSYAASU4E94H3kb3D8j8wbG4wFJgMvyra0%203vJxL2bAl6DrFQYkbGAwGIHQYA7ER1gtSdHlTWBEGQT1rknWV1w3K4WXib8RmuN5HiA3BfzxTBRCY-V6FwjUGg%20eg3l5AVwAgbdtFYcFTg4IRRXFSU4HVGB3gRIA):

```
interface DataItem {
    text: string
    list: string[]
}

function isListItem(item: string): boolean {
    return item.startsWith('-') && item.endsWith(';')
}

const transformedData = data.reduce<DataItem[]>((acc, item) => {
    // if item is list item
    if (isListItem(item)) {
        // get last DataItem from acc
        const lastDataItem = acc[acc.length - 1]

        // and use it as list item's parent
        if (lastDataItem) {
            lastDataItem.list.push(item)
        } else {
            console.error(`Parent text not found for list item ${item}`)
        }

        return acc
    }

    // if item is not list item, use it as new parent/DataItem
    const dataItem: DataItem = {
        text: item,
        list: []
    }

    return [...acc, dataItem]
}, [])
```

What it missing is ignoring the sections. Any ideas how to modify that reduce function so it will produce expected result?

To determine a section I came up with this funciton:

```
function isSection(item: string): boolean {
    return item.startsWith('+') && item.endsWith('+')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the same approach from my answer to another (formerly asked) question of the OP ... [*"Transform array in to object with custom properties"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010046/transform-array-in-to-object-with-custom-properties/72011499#72011499) ... and adapt it according to the OP's new requirements.

Thus one would stay with the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which does not depend on outer scope references for keeping track of the currently to be built/aggregated property but instead makes this information part of the reducer function's first parameter, [the `previousValue` which serves as an accumulator/collector object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#grouping_objects_by_a_property).

As for the OP's task, this collector would feature 2 properties, the `sectionKey` and the `result`, where the former holds the state of the currently processed property name, and the latter being the programmatically built `result`-array of section-items.

```js
function aggregateStructuredTextItem(
  { sectionKey = '', result = [] },
  item
) {
  // try to retrieve the section specific text.
  let text = (item.match(/^\+\s*(.*?)\s*\+$/) || [])[1] ?? null;
  if (
    (text !== null) &&
    (text !== sectionKey)
  ) {
    // keep track of the currently processed section.    
    sectionKey = text;

    // create and collect new section entry.
    result.push({ section: text, content: [] });
  } else {
    // access the currently processed section.
    const section = result.at(-1);

    // try to retrieve the list specific text.
    text = (item.startsWith('-') && item.slice(1));
    if (text !== false) {

      // push list specific text into
      // the most recent content list.
      section.content.at(-1).list.push(text);
    } else {
      // create a content item and push it
      // into the most recent section content.
      section.content.push({ text: item, list: [] });
    }
  }
  return { sectionKey, result };
}

const textData = [
  '+section1+',
  'big text 1 here.',
  'big text 2 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '+section2+',
  'big text 3 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '+section3+', 
  'big text 4 here.'
];
const structuredTextData = textData
  .reduce(aggregateStructuredTextItem, { result: [] })
  .result;

console.log({ textData, structuredTextData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it

```js
const data= [
  '+section1+',
  'big text 1 here.',
  'big text 2 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '+section2+',
  'big text 3 here followed by list:',
  '-this is list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '-this is another list item;',
  '+section3+', 
  'big text 4 here.'
]



const result = data.reduce((res, item) =>{
  if(item.startsWith('+')){
    const section = item.substring(1, item.length -1)
    return[
        ...res,
       {
         section,
         content: []
       } 
      ]
  }
   const lastSectionIndex = res.length - 1
  if(item.startsWith('-')){
    const lastSection = res[lastSectionIndex]
    const lastContent = lastSection.content[lastSection.content.length -1]
    res[res.length - 1].content[lastSection.content.length -1].list.push(item.substring(1, item.length -1))
    return res
  }
  res[lastSectionIndex].content.push({text: item, list:[]})
 return res;

},[])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: any ideas why when it runs within jsbin, it produces different result ? https://jsbin.com/coxehiqibi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: I've checked and the result is the same. `jsbin` hust adds some tag to the console output like `[object Object]`so it seems different.

Comment: I wonder why it outputs `sections` as a last item...

Comment: @sreginogemoh yes but in the same object. The keys are in a different order but the object is the same